# Match string with php dom xpath by first and last character

Tags: php, dom, xpath

I want to match html string(s) starting with % and ending with % character by searching the text with xpath.

Conditions:

- **String starts with %**
- **String ends with %**
- **Can have none or multiple matches within one html document**
- String can contain (but is optinional) :: but needs at least 1
  alphabetic character before and after the ::
- Between the first and last % alphabetic, numeric and - characters are
  allowed.

The best I got was `$xpath->query("//*[text()[starts-with(., '%')][substring(., string-length(.) - 1) = '%']]");`

But that is not working. New to the php Dom stuff and finding it hard to get to answers on my own. Explanations are greatly valued!

Thanks in advance!

**Edit**

See the comments below that in this case the use of preg_match_all is beter. Currently I'm using the following code for this:

```
preg_match_all('/%{1}[a-zA-Z0-9-]+?(::?[a-zA-Z0-9-]+?)?%{1}/', $string, $match);
```

Improvements for this pattern are accepted.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't XPath's strong point - what you're describing would be best handled by a REGEXP engine (which, in PHP, would presumably mean iterating over the nodes and running each one through `preg_match`).

Nonetheless, here's a (very) hacky XPath approach which I *think* does what you want. You can see a working demo at **[this XMLPlayground](http://www.xmlplayground.com/6M3mct)**.

```
root/node[
    substring(., 1, 1) = '%' and
    substring(., string-length(.)) = '%' and
    not(string-length(translate(substring(., 2, string-length(.)-2), 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-:', ''))) and
    (
        (
            contains(., '::') and
            substring(., 2, 1) != ':' and
            substring(., string-length(.)-2, 1) != ':'
        ) or
        not(contains(., '::'))
    )

]
```

Comment: $module = $xpath->query("//*[text()[
    substring(., 1, 1) = '%' and
    substring(., string-length(.)) = '%' and
    not(string-length(translate(substring(., 2, string-length(.)-2), 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-:', ''))) and
    (
     (
      contains(., '::') and
      substring(., 2, 1) != ':' and
      substring(., string-length(.)-2, 1) != ':'
     ) or
     not(contains(., '::'))
    )

   ]]");
  
  print_r($module);

The value for modules then is DOMNodeList Object ( [length] => 0 ).

Comment: Furthermore, I've read that xpath is better then using REGEXP engine  in terms of speed and performance. I know how to do this with regex but like to learn more about php dom. I'm using it for more things like changing links and images and it works very well. Maybey php dom is not cut out for this things and I should use it more for targetting html tags.

Comment: Running is faster than walking but you wouldn't do it carrying a tray of drinks. My point is, speed is only one factor; XPath functions are not designed for serious string-handling or REGEX-like enforcement. Even so, my answer was totally XPath.

Comment: Unfortunately your answer is not working, even if i cut the solution back to root/node[substring(., 1, 1) = '%' and substring(., string-length(.)) = '%']

Comment: OK. It visibly works at the example I linked to, which is actually handled by PHP in the background, so I'm not sure why it wouldn't work in your case.

Comment: Maybe because I'm not working with XML but with HTML strings. This is what I'm using: $xpath->query("//*[substring(., 1, 1) = '%' and substring(., string-length(.)) = '%']")
I think I'm going for a regex solution considoring your feedback. I'm adding this information as well later on. I want the DOM solution working so we can leave this with a solution for others to learn from :) Then I will mark the solution as answered as well :)